# fork() in C++ Learning os development

Tags: c++, operating-system

I am learning OS development with C/C++ and i am using fork() method to experiment with process. I have the following code like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    fork(); //create a child process, currently total is 1 parent, 1 child
    fork(); //create a child process,currently total is 2 parents, 2 child
    pid_t pid;
    if((pid=fork()) == 0) { //fork() and assign to pid, now has 4 parents, 4 childs
        printf("I am the child: %u\n", getpid());
    else {
        printf("I am the parent: %u and my child is: %u\n", getpid(), pid);
    }
}
```

When i compile it, and run it, it shows 4 parents and 4 children as i expected, however the output looks strange to me (notice the bolded line below where i get the output after user@slacker:~$).

> > user@slacker:~$ gcc forktest.c -o forktest
> >
> > user@slacker:~$ ./forktest
> >
> > I am the parent: 1183 and my child is: 1186
> >
> > **user@slacker:~$ I am the parent: 1184 and my child is: 1188**
> >
> > I am the parent: 1185 and my child is: 1189
> >
> > I am the parent: 1187 and my child is: 1190
> >
> > I am the child: 1186
> >
> > I am the child: 1189
> >
> > I am the child: 1190
> >
> > I am the child: 1191

When i tried with 3 fork(), the output is even stranger. Can someone explain to me please?

Comment: The program execution of the first process completed. The first process called fork() twice, and continued calling pid=fork(), and since it is parent, it printed it and exited. The order of execution will vary everytime. The sceduler decides it. So, dont worry :)

Comment: when i tried using 3 fork(), it outputs 11 lines first then the user@slacker:~$ reappear again at line 12. Is it normal?

Comment: I ran both the versions of fork(). As noticed, the order of execution was different all the time. It is absolutely norrmal. For more info, follow do_fork() function in linux kernel, and the context_switch() also. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ohh i see, it is good to know it is normal. I thought i did something wrong. Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
         fork            fork            fork
  1183----+---------------+----------------+-------------------->
          |               |                |
          |               |           1186 +-------------------->
          |               |
          |         1185  +----------------+-------------------->
          |                                |
          |                           1189 +-------------------->
          |
  1184    +---------------+----------------+-------------------->
                          |                |
                          |           1188 +-------------------->
                          |
                  1187    +----------------+-------------------->
                                           |
                                      1190 +-------------------->
```

created with http://www.asciiflow.com/#Draw

Comment: Thanks! It is easier to track my process creation now by using your diagram!